# Jensen's inequality but with geometric mean

Tags: calculus, inequality, convex-analysis, functional-inequalities, jensen-inequality

If the inequality $f({\sqrt x}{\sqrt y})⩽{\sqrt f(x)}{\sqrt f(y)}$ is satisfied for all non negative $x,y$ in the domain, what can we say about the convexity of $f$ ? Or are there any other properties of this type of functions?

Comment: Since any function $f_\alpha(x) = x^\alpha, \, \alpha > 0$
satisfies your inequality we cannot say anything about the convexity. Indeed, for $0 < \alpha \le 1$  $f_\alpha$ if concave, while for $\alpha \ge 1$ it's convex.

Comment: Consider $g(t) = \ln \circ f \circ \exp$ or something similar. What can you say about $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f : \mathbb{R_+} \to \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $f$ is (weakly) decreasing,

$$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \leq f(\sqrt{xy}) \leq \sqrt{f(x)f(y)} \leq \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2}$$

implies that $f$ is (weakly) convex.

Without any restriction on the function $f$, you can't conclude anything. Take $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ defined over $\mathbb{R}_+$. It satisfies $(xy)^{0.25} = f\left(\sqrt{xy}\right) \leq \sqrt{f(x)f(y)} = (xy)^{0.25}$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_+$ but is concave.